# what should I do for "com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException"?

Tags: java, cassandra, garbage-collection, cassandra-2.0

I put almost `190 million records` in Cassandra(2.1.11) cluster with 3 nodes, and the replication factor is `1` , then I write client application to count the all records using [datastax's `Java Driver`](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver),  the snippet code as follows:

```
Statement stmt = new SimpleStatement("select * from test" );

System.out.println("starting to read records ");
stmt.setFetchSize(10000);
ResultSet rs = session.execute(stmt);

//System.out.println("rs.size " + rs.all().size());
long cntRecords = 0;

for(Row row : rs){
    cntRecords++;

    if(cntRecords % 10000000 == 0){
        System.out.println("the " + cntRecords/10000000 + " X 10 millions of records");
    }
}
```

After the above variable `cntRecords` is more than 30 millions,   I always get the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: 
Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency ONE (1 responses were required but only 
0 replica responded)
```

I got several results in google and changed the settings about heap and GC, the following is my relative settings:

```
-XX:InitialHeapSize=17179869184 
-XX:MaxHeapSize=17179869184 
-XX:MaxNewSize=12884901888 
-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1 
-XX:NewSize=12884901888 
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly 
-XX:+UseCompressedOops 
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC 
-XX:+UseCondCardMark 
-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation 
-XX:+UseParNewGC 
-XX:+UseTLAB 
-XX:+UseThreadPriorities
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
```

and I used [GCViewer](https://github.com/chewiebug/GCViewer) to analysis the gc log file and the througputs are 99.95%, 98.15% and 95.75%.

UPDATED BEGIN: 
And I used `jstat` to monitor one of the three nodes and found that when the `S1`'s value changed into `100.00` I will get the above error quickly:

```
/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/jstat -gcutil 8862 1000 
S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT   
0.00 100.00  28.57  36.29  74.66     55   14.612     2    0.164   14.776
```

And once `S1` changed into `100.00`, `S1` no longer will decrease, I don't know this is relative to the error? Or what property in `cassandra.yaml` or `cassandra-env.sh` I should set for this?

What should I do for finishing the task to count the all records? Thanks in advance!

ATTACH:
 the following is other options:

```
-XX:+CMSEdenChunksRecordAlways 
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 
-XX:+CMSParallelInitialMarkEnabled 
-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled 
-XX:CMSWaitDuration=10000 
-XX:CompileCommandFile=bin/../conf/hotspot_compiler 
-XX:GCLogFileSize=94371840 
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError 
-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=90 
-XX:OldPLABSize=16 
-XX:PrintFLSStatistics=1 
-XX:+PrintGC 
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime 
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps 
-XX:+PrintGCDetails 
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps 
-XX:+PrintHeapAtGC 
-XX:+PrintPromotionFailure 
-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution 
-XX:StringTableSize=1000003 
-XX:SurvivorRatio=8 
-XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 
-XX:ThreadStackSize=256
```

Comment: I assume you know what "timeout" means? just read x records at a time, instead of all at once

Comment: @Stultuske, Thank you for your reminding me, but I don't know what's your  meaning? I hope you talk more about what should I do? or tell me what things I should understand

Comment: don't try to read 30 million records in one go, you'll get a time out. read the first x, then the next x, then the next x, ... until you've read them all. x is an amount you set, based on what would be more efficient in your case.

Comment: @Stultuske, you mean I should not use `Statement stmt = new SimpleStatement("select * from test" );`?

Comment: Have you considered thinking it through? your connection obviously can't manage the 30 million, and that's not surprisingly.
If you had to transport 30 million kids to school, and you only had one bus, would you try to cram them all in, or would you make the trip several times?

Comment: @Stultuske what's your meaning "your connection obviously can't manage the 30 million" , I can get 30 million, but I can not get more than 30 million, after I get 30 million I got the exception. Other side, why do you think my connection obviously can not manage the 30 million, thanks for your patience!

Comment: @Stultuske, I thought about your words: "your connection obviously can't manage the 30 million", you means that the connection using datastax's Java driver I created can not mangage the 30 million, I am right? If yes, answer I want to know is that how to separate the query "select * from test" into mult-connection? Thanks a lot!

Comment: TimeOut means you have a limited time after which the connection sort of dies. Executing yours take more time. So: run the query several times, but each time for (for instance) 1000 records, and load them part by part.

Comment: @Stultuske, thank you! How to run the query (`select * from test`) several times? I only know `select * from test limit 1000`, but I don't know how to query the next 1000 ? I am so sorry for this simple question!

Comment: What does `nodetool cfstats` give you for max compacted partition bytes on this table?

Comment: @Stultuske the driver already does that for you. Notice the line that says `stmt.setFetchSize(10000)`, that's the size of the bus. @abelard2008 any errors in server-side logs?

Comment: @OlivierMichallat, Thank you for your reminding `stmt.setFetchSize(10000)`. Other side, I did not find any errors in server-side logs, In fact, I  monitored cluster's nodes using `jstat` and found that I will get the exception when I [jstat -gcutil ...](http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/how-to-monitor-java-garbage-collection/) 's `S1` is  100%, I don't know they are relative?

Comment: @rs_atl, the results are: `Compacted partition minimum bytes: 373
                Compacted partition maximum bytes: 8239
                Compacted partition mean bytes: 627`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Examine *why* you need to know the number of rows.  Does your application really need to know this?  If it can survive with "just" a good approximation, then create a counter and increment it as you load your data.

http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_counter_t.html

Things you can try:

- Select a single column instead of `*`.  This might reduce by GC pressure and network consumption.  Preferably pick a column that has a small number of bytes and is part of the primary key: `select column1 from test`
- Add a short pause after every 1M records.  Have your loop pause for 500ms or so every 1M records.  This may give the nodes a quick breather to take care of things like GC
- Edit `cassandra.yaml` on your nodes and increase `range_request_timeout_in_ms` and `read_request_timeout_in_ms`
- Figure out the token ranges assigned to each node and issue a separate query for each token range.  Add the counts from each query.  This takes advantage of the token-aware driver to issue each "token range" query directly to the node that can answer it.  See this [blog article](http://www.planetcassandra.org/blog/data-locality-w-cassandra-how-to-scan-the-local-token-range-of-a-table/) for a full description with sample code.

Comment: @@Brandon, Thank you! No, this is not necessary to know the the number , and I have experience how to use `counter`, I only just want to test the cassandra cluster through reading all records continually, this result make me further want to know why it can not read more than 30 million records, do you think it is relative to `jstat -gcutil ...` 's `S1`, or after `S1` reach to `100`, why it does not decrease any longer, what should I do?

Comment: Edited the post and added some things you can try

Comment: @@brandon, Thank you very much!, I will try this when I get to my office

Comment: @abelard2008 can you share which step(s) solved your issue?